# Searching on case insensitive string in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
    let helpData = [
      {
        "question": "Question = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        "answer": "Answer = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
      },
      {
        "question": "Question = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        "answer": "Answer = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
      },
      {
        "question": "Question = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        "answer": "Answer = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
      },
  {
"question": "Question = Capital of India",
"answer": "Answer = Delhi."
},
    ];

    let search = "capital";
    const res = helpData.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(val => val.includes(search)));
    console.log(res)
```

I want to search based on given string. If case matches above code works fine but for insensitive case it doesn't work.
Please help to find a solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2140627/438992

Comment: Unrelated, but I wouldn't put non-question/-answer text in the question and answer; their nature is included in the code.

Comment: `search.match`, it should be just `search` and it should work fine with case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let helpData = [
  {
    "question": "Question = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "answer": "Answer = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  },
  {
    "question": "Question = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "answer": "Answer = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  },
  {
    "question": "Question = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "answer": "Answer = Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  },
];

let regexp = /Lorem Ipsum/gm;

const even = (element) => element.match(regexp);
const resp = helpData.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(even));

console.log(resp);
```

**Solution**:

For **Case Insensitive String**

`let regexp = /Lorem Ipsum/gmi;`

For **Case Sensitive String**

`let regexp = /Lorem Ipsum/gm;`

```
const even = (element) => element.match(regexp);
const resp = helpData.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(even));
console.log(resp);
```