# Hangman case insensesetive

Tags: javascript

we are in our 3 week of our Bootcamp.
Project is to code the Hangman game, it is running in the terminal.
We got preety far in just 2 days I think.
We are now stucked on the case insensesetivity, meaning if the word we are looking for is Java that if you type j or J, you still would get the same result J_ _ _.
I looked all over the Internet and found the locale.compare method which isn´t working for me. If i type a wrong letter everything is fine but if I type a right one I get a error and also it doesn´t ignore the case of the letter.
We are not using functions yet because we haven´t learned how they work.

```js
const constants = require('./constants');
// In node.js: install a prompt library by running: `npm install prompt-sync` in the current folder
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();

// Here you see an example how to get your
// constants from constants.js
/*for(let figure of constants.HANGMAN_PICS)
{
   console.log(figure);
}
*/
let Answer = [];

var Words = constants.WORDS_TO_GUESS[Math.floor(Math.random() * constants.WORDS_TO_GUESS.length)];

/*console.log(Words.length);                 //Wortlänge von random Word
 */

for (let i = 0; i < Words.length; i++) {
  Answer[i] = "_";
}

console.log(Answer.join(" "));


for (; Answer !== Words;) {
  input = prompt(`Finde das Wort.`);

  if (Words.includes(input)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < Words.length; i++) {
      if (Words[i] === input) {
        Answer[i] = input;
      }
    }

    console.log(Answer.join(" "));
    console.log(Answer.localeCompare(Words, {
      sensitivity: `base`
    }));

  } else if (!Words.includes(input)) {
    console.log("Falsche Eingabe - keep trying!");
    console.log(Answer.join(" "))
  }

}

// how to use the prompt - e.g.:
// const name = prompt('What is your name?');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do case insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/how-to-do-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 1):

my way of doing this (which may not be the best) is setting both strings to lower case and comparing them with **`includes()`** function.
The for loop afterwards will just collect right position/s that you want to show up after right guess.

```js
const word = 'JavaScript'
const char = 's' //input
const indexes = [] //output

//https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes 
//includes() function
if(word.toLowerCase().includes(char.toLowerCase())){ 
   //if you need to get the index/es of the latter/s 
   for (let i = 0; i < word.toLowerCase().length; i++) {
      if (word.toLowerCase()[i] === char.toLowerCase()) {
        indexes.push(i)
      }
   }
}

console.log(indexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Words` (which should be `word`, singular and not capitalized) is in lower case (or upper case) by doing `.toLocaleLowerCase()` (or `.toLocaleUpperCase()`) at the end of where you assign it:

```
var Words = constants.WORDS_TO_GUESS[Math.floor(Math.random() * constants.WORDS_TO_GUESS.length)].toLocaleLowerCase();
// >>> −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then make sure `input` is lower case (or upper case):

```
input = prompt(`Finde das Wort.`).toLocaleLowerCase();
```

At that point, you'll be comparing `j` and `j` (or `J` and `J`), so you'll find a match.

---

If you don't want to consistently use one capitalization in your code, it's *possible* to do it differently, but more complicated.

Basically, you do the `.toLocaleLowerCase()` (or `.toLocaleUpperCase()`) **everywhere** you do a comparison:

```
for (; Answer !== Words;) {
    input = prompt(`Finde das Wort.`).toLocaleLowerCase();
// Get the input in lower case −−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    if (Words.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(input)) {
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−− make Words lower case for the includes call
        for (let i = 0; i < Words.length; i++) {
            if (Words[i].toLocaleLowerCase() === input) {
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−− make Words[i] lower case for the ===
                Answer[i] = Words[i];
//                          ^^^^^^^^−−− use the one from Words, not the user's input
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use this code i can press J or j but if i press j the Java would be writen in lowercases so it would print out java not Java

Comment: @B.N.B - Your best bet is to pick the one you want to display (upper or lower case) and use that consistently (by using `.toLocaleLowerCase()` or `.toLocaleUpperCase()` depending on which one you want). It's **possible** to use mixed case, but it would look odd in a Hangman game.

Comment: @B.N.B - I've updated the answer to show how you might do that, but I wouldn't. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help I now works and shows the letters in the same case as in die word file