# jquery insert option before option with greater class

Tags: jquery

Hi i want create function which will after clicking button remove option from one list and insert in to another but `before` option with `class` with grater suffix than one that i selected. Class name is `opt_$i` so when i select `opt_4` i want to insert it before `opt` which is greater (its not always 5 it can be 73)

```
function minus(id)
{
    var c = $('select#'+ id +' option:selected');
    var cities = $('select[name=cities] option');

    c.each(function(){
       var item = $(this);
       var current = parseInt($(this).attr('class').replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));

       cities.each(function(){
           var next = parseInt($(this).attr('class').replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));

           if(next > current)
           {
               var next_item = $(this);
               return; // I dont know why this doesnt work ??
           }
       });
       /**
       if(previouse == 1)
       {
           $('select[name=cities] option:first').before(
                $('<option></option>')
                    .attr('value', current.val())
                    .attr('class', current.attr('class'))
                    .text(current.text())
           );    
       }
       else
       {
       */
           //$('select[name=cities] option[class=opt_'+ previouse +']').next()
           next_item.before(
                $('<option></option>')
                    .attr('value', current.val())
                    .attr('class', current.attr('class'))
                    .text(current.text())
           );
       //}
       $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Is there better way to achive this ?? Than looping every time list in which i want to insert option to find greater class value ??

**Edit:**

```
<select id="a">
  <option class="opt_3">a</option>
</select>

<select id="b">
 <option class="opt_1">c</option>
 <option class="opt_7">d</option>
</select>
```

after clicking on button i want to remove option from list `a` and insert to list `b` but before `opt_7`. How to find option which has class greater than opt_3 ??

**SOULUTION**
http://jsfiddle.net/Atm8V/6/ here is how it should work, thanks for all comments.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is your code throwing any kind of error, or is it just failing silently?  2) Have you stepped through the code or thrown in some alerts to see what the values of `next` and `current` are to make sure they're what you expect?  You'll get better and faster help if you can better define what is going wrong.

Comment: `var next_item = $(this);` this is ok but loop is not stopping on `return` and I get `Error: next_item is not defined
Source File: http://mk.ie/back/location/add
Line: 186` at the end of loop

Comment: The next_item error is easy - you declare the variable inside of the if statement `if(next > current)` so it's out of scope when you attempt to call the before function.

Comment: From your example, assuming that element with id "b" is the cities select, you would need to alter that select like so: `<select id="b" name="cities">`.  Using the name selector means that you need to have an  element with that name.  As it is now, cities does not evaluate to an element so you never enter the `cities.each` method.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Atm8V/ here JSLint shows that code is valid but its not working. Options is not moving from cities to `column_1` on my localhost it works

Comment: jsFiddle wraps your JavaScript in a $(document).ready function, so you'll need to add your onclick handlers using jQuery.

Comment: @MarkM thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/Atm8V/5/ now plus work.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are removing and inserting elements between the select's you'll need to do some type of sorting.

If you're moving mostly single options from select to select it's probably better to do that by iterating through the target select at the time of insertion than to call a sort algorithm that may not be optimized for the degree of sorted-ness that your option list will have, although the performance difference on this point may be negligible.

If you expect multiple items to be moved at once on a regular basis it might be better to insert them into the target select and then use jQuery's sort method [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-sort-an-html-selects-options-by-value-while).  That would get rid of the explicit inner loop in your code (by hiding it in the sort).

The difference between the two options is, of course, dependent on the length of the options list and, as I implied previously, the average expected number of items transferred at a time.  If the insert-all-items-then-sort method works for you I'd follow that route because your code will be more modular and easily readable.