# Sorting options elements alphabetically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I'm trying to understand sorting `option` elements within a `select` element alphabetically. Ideally, I'd like to have this as a separate function where I can just pass in the select element since it needs to be sorted when the user clicks some buttons.

I've searched high and low for a good way of doing this, but haven't been able to find anything that worked for me.

The option elements should be sorted alphabetically by text, not value.

Is this possible in some way?

Comment: So basically you want to give a selector and order all of his children alphabetically by the text they contain ?

Comment: I think you should view this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery

Comment: @pkurek: In all it's simplicity, yes :-) kaz: Yeah, I've fooled around with that snippet, but simply can't get it to work :-/ Wondered if there were any other way to do it.

Comment: @bomortensen: All solutions will be essentially similar. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1134983/218196) is as easy as it can get.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

What I'd do is:

1. Extract the text and value of each `<option>` into an array of objects;
2. Sort the array;
3. Update the `<option>` elements with the array contents in order.

To do that with jQuery, you could do this:

```
var options = $('select.whatever option');
var arr = options.map(function(_, o) { return { t: $(o).text(), v: o.value }; }).get();
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) { return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0; });
options.each(function(i, o) {
  o.value = arr[i].v;
  $(o).text(arr[i].t);
});
```

[Here is a working jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/trELD/)

*edit* — If you want to sort such that you ignore alphabetic case, you can use the JavaScript `.toUpperCase()` or `.toLowerCase()` functions before comparing:

```
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
  var t1 = o1.t.toLowerCase(), t2 = o2.t.toLowerCase();

  return t1 > t2 ? 1 : t1 < t2 ? -1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: This did it for me! Just had to make all the > and < checks to upper case :-) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Ah OK right, if you want to ignore alphabetic case then yes. Glad it worked!

Comment: yes, because JS weighs uppercase characters higher than lowercase when sorting.. so it seems ;-) Thanks again, works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for this answer - solved my problem almost entirely. I just needed to augment it to account for tracking the selected option. For the arr options.map I added "s: $(o).attr('selected')", and then in options.each just needed to add: $(o).attr('selected', arr[i].s); Thanks!

Comment: I am new to jquery - where would I add the check for the upper case as mentioned by bomortensen?

Comment: @user1261774 if you want to sort without regard to alphabetic case, you can use some functions to convert the strings. I'll extend the answer.

Comment: Here's the amended code to remember the currently selected option: http://jsfiddle.net/trELD/700/

Comment: Seems to work without the get method.  And how are you using that [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) without a key?

Comment: @GeoffreyHale it probably does work without `.get()`; the jQuery object more-or-less mimics an array. When you call `.get()` with no key, you get back a *real* array containing the DOM elements.

Comment: may i know what is the meaning of passing a underscore in jquery .map() function

Comment: Why not use `value` and `text` as propertynames? Your minimizer will get rid of it :). Great answer though, thanks

Answer (score 70):

Accepted answer is not the best in all cases because sometimes you want to perserve classes of options and different arguments (for example data-foo).

My solution is:

```
var sel = $('#select_id');
var selected = sel.val(); // cache selected value, before reordering
var opts_list = sel.find('option');
opts_list.sort(function(a, b) { return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1; });
sel.html('').append(opts_list);
sel.val(selected); // set cached selected value
```

//For ie11 or those who get a blank options, replace html('') empty()

Comment: Best answer. This is my case. I need to keep option data attrs

Comment: Easy and simplified answer.

Comment: In the last line, you can change sel.html('').append(opts_list) to simply sel.html(opts_list)

Comment: Should be noted that it does not work in ie(11) : the options lose their labels. The most cross-browser solution I found is [a jquery-less one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1885355/2572988).

Comment: This should be the selected answer! This is much simpler than above, and preserves any classes or data attributes.

Comment: if you want to per perform case insensitive sorting do the following `return $(a).text().toLowerCase() > $(b).text().toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;`

Answer (score 40):

#### html:

```
<select id="list">
    <option value="op3">option 3</option>
    <option value="op1">option 1</option>
    <option value="op2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

#### jQuery:

```
var options = $("#list option");                    // Collect options         
options.detach().sort(function(a,b) {               // Detach from select, then Sort
    var at = $(a).text();
    var bt = $(b).text();         
    return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);            // Tell the sort function how to order
});
options.appendTo("#list");                          // Re-attach to select
```

I used tracevipin's solution, which worked fantastically. I provide a slightly modified version here for anyone like me who likes to find easily readable code, and compress it *after* it's understood. I've also used `.detach` instead of `.remove` to preserve any bindings on the option DOM elements.

Comment: Worked for me perfectly

Comment: This is the best solution IMO and very similar to what I was going to post since it preserves the state of the elements (even for multiple selections).

Comment: Works for me perfectly as well.

Comment: almost perfect, but Chrome and Firefox show the last option as selected.

Comment: To fix Chrome and Firefox last option selected, just keep track of the original value with this code at the beginning and end of this answer`var original = $("#list").val(); //first line
$("#list").val(original); //last line`

Answer (score 32):

```
<select id="mSelect" >
    <option value="val1" > DEF </option>
    <option value="val4" > GRT </option>
    <option value="val2" > ABC </option>
    <option value="val3" > OPL </option>
    <option value="val5" > AWS </option>
    <option value="val9" > BTY </option>
</select>
```

.

```
$("#mSelect").append($("#mSelect option").remove().sort(function(a, b) {
    var at = $(a).text(), bt = $(b).text();
    return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);
}));
```

Comment: `$("#mSelect").append($options);` should suffice :)

Comment: The callback to `.sort()` should return a number that's less than zero, zero, or greater, to reflect the ordering relationship. Returning a boolean won't really work right I don't think.

Comment: I went with the above, changed to: var at = $(a).text().toLowerCase(), bt = $(b).text().toLowerCase(); to make sorting case independent

Answer (score 8):

I know this topic is old but I think my answer can be useful for a lot of people.

Here is jQuery plugin made from **Pointy**'s answer using ES6:

```
/**
 * Sort values alphabetically in select
 * source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073270/sorting-options-elements-alphabetically-using-jquery
 */
$.fn.extend({
    sortSelect() {
        let options = this.find("option"),
            arr = options.map(function(_, o) { return { t: $(o).text(), v: o.value }; }).get();

        arr.sort((o1, o2) => { // sort select
            let t1 = o1.t.toLowerCase(), 
                t2 = o2.t.toLowerCase();
            return t1 > t2 ? 1 : t1 < t2 ? -1 : 0;
        });

        options.each((i, o) => {
            o.value = arr[i].v;
            $(o).text(arr[i].t);
        });
    }
});
```

Use is very easy

```
$("select").sortSelect();
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's my improved version of [Pointy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12073377/2930272):

```
function sortSelectOptions(selector, skip_first) {
    var options = (skip_first) ? $(selector + ' option:not(:first)') : $(selector + ' option');
    var arr = options.map(function(_, o) { return { t: $(o).text(), v: o.value, s: $(o).prop('selected') }; }).get();
    arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
      var t1 = o1.t.toLowerCase(), t2 = o2.t.toLowerCase();
      return t1 > t2 ? 1 : t1 < t2 ? -1 : 0;
    }); 
    options.each(function(i, o) {
        o.value = arr[i].v;
        $(o).text(arr[i].t);
        if (arr[i].s) {
            $(o).attr('selected', 'selected').prop('selected', true);
        } else {
            $(o).removeAttr('selected');
            $(o).prop('selected', false);
        }
    }); 
}
```

The function has the `skip_first` parameter, which is useful when you want to keep the first option on top, e.g. when it's "choose below:".

It also keeps track of the previously selected option.

Example usage:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  sortSelectOptions('#select-id', true);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers worked for me.  For some strange reason, when looping through the options, each option returns nothing when `text()` is called.  Instead, I was forced to retrieve the option's label via `attr('label')`

```
/**
 * Sort the options of the target select list
 * alphabetically by label. For some reason, when
 * we call detach(), the returned options have no
 * text() and instead we're forced to get the option's
 * label via the 'label' attribute.
 * @param select jQuery selector
 */
function sort_multi_select(select) {
    var options = select.find('option');
    options.detach().sort(function (a, b) {
        var at = $(a).attr('label'), //label, not text()
            bt = $(b).attr('label');
        return at > bt ? 1 : at < bt ? -1 : 0;
    });
    options.appendTo(select);
}

//example
sort_multi_select($('#my_select'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I combined parts from [marxin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26232541/1430996) and [kuxa's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40070149/1430996) excellent answers to create a jQuery custom function that

1. sorts the options by their text values (case-insensitive),
2. maintains any already-selected value, **and**
3. returns the original jQuery objects against which the function is executed:

   ```
   $.fn.extend({
       sortSelect() {
           return this.each(function(){
               let $this = $(this),
                   original_selection = $this.val(),
                   $options = $this.find('option'),
                   arr = $options.map(function(_, o) { return { t: $(o).text(), v: o.value }; }).get();

               arr.sort((o1, o2) => {
                   // sort select
                   let t1 = o1.t.toLowerCase(), 
                       t2 = o2.t.toLowerCase();
                   return t1 > t2 ? 1 : t1 < t2 ? -1 : 0;
               });

               $options.each((i, o) => {
                   o.value = arr[i].v;
                   $(o).text(arr[i].t);
               });

               $this.val(original_selection); 
           })
       }
   });
   ```

[Working example on jsFiddle is available at https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/64och25e/](https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/64och25e/).

Comment: I love that I could use some of the time this Q/A saved me by enhancing the answers in a way that hopefully benefits someone else. Viva Stack Overflow!!!

Comment: Please note that this way doesn't preserve data-xxx="abc" and moves the option order to another one which may create risky cases

Answer (score 1):

The [jquery.selectboxes.js](http://marcj.github.io/jquery-selectBox/) plugin has a sort method. You can implement the plugin, or dive into the code to see a way to sort the options.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can sort the options by its text and append it back to the select box.

```
 function NASort(a, b) {    
      if (a.innerHTML == 'NA') {
          return 1;   
      }
      else if (b.innerHTML == 'NA') {
          return -1;   
      }       
      return (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML) ? 1 : -1;
  };
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vaishali_ravisankar/5zfohf6v/

Answer (score 1):

Malakgeorge answer is nice an can be easily wrapped into a jQuery function:

```
$.fn.sortSelectByText = function(){
    this.each(function(){
        var selected = $(this).val(); 
        var opts_list = $(this).find('option');
        opts_list.sort(function(a, b) { return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1; });
        $(this).html('').append(opts_list);
        $(this).val(selected); 
    })
    return this;        
}
```

Comment: It's a good solution but it doesn't work in IE11. When I applied this function to the dropdown list, the options' text gets empty. If you replace .html('') with .empty(), it should work.

Comment: Thank you for this comment !