# Calling a function in a jQuery event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a pair of `<select>` boxes and have a jQuery script to transfer selected `<option>`s from one select box to the other. I also have a function to do the opposite. This works fine except when I "put back" the `<option>`s to the first `<select>` they are appended to the bottom instead of alphabetically as before.

So I found this function courtesy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073270/sorting-options-elements-alphabetically-using-jquery):

```
function sortSelect() {
    var options = $('#inactiveTickers option');
    var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
        return {
            t: $(o).text(),
            v: o.value
        };
    }).get();
    arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
        return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
    });
    options.each(function(i, o) {
        console.log(i);
        o.value = arr[i].v;
        $(o).text(arr[i].t);
    });
}
```

Then I have this jQuery which captures the click event on a link with id `#remove`:

```
$('#remove').click(function() {  
    return !$('#activeTickers option:selected').remove().appendTo('#inactiveTickers');  
    sortSelect();
  });
```

So the first line in the function does the moving of the `<option>` tags and the second should call the `sortSelect` function.
The trouble is I don't think the `sortSelect` function is being called (there is nothing in the console log and the function should write to it). What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You have `return` in first line, the execution ends there...

Comment: Also, your `sortSelect` function sorts only `select#inactiveTickers` - You might want to make that an argument as well..

Comment: @techfoobar Yes, I will make it an argument, just wanted to get it working first. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions stops when you use they're return . I don't understand why you're using a return to do that stuff ,considering that `appendTo()` does not return anything (btw you don't need to `return` anything) . Just do

```
$('#remove').click(function() {  
$('#activeTickers option:selected').remove().appendTo('#inactiveTickers');  
sortSelect();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are already returning some value before you call `sortSelect`, the function call ends in the line of `return`. Just do not return anything or put the value into a variable an return it after you have called `sortSelect`.

```
$('#remove').click(function() {  
    var ret = !$('#activeTickers option:selected').remove().appendTo('#inactiveTickers');  
    sortSelect();
    return ret;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your method probably works but as @steo said the first line doesn't return anything so best just to call it without return.