# Inserting an input into a select by order

Tags: jquery

```
HTML:
<select id="list">
    <option value="A">Alpha</option>
    <option value="B">Bravo</option>
    <option value="D">Delta</option>
</select>

jQuery:
$("#list").append("<option value=\"C\">Charlie</option>");
```

Is there any easy way to get option C between B and D?

Comment: See there to sort options alphabetically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12073377/1414562

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$("<option value=\"C\">Charlie</option>").insertAfter('#list > option[value="B"]');
```

...or [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/):

```
$("<option value=\"C\">Charlie</option>").insertBefore('#list > option[value="D"]');
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7stLp/3/)

Comment: This will require him to always count the elements to know the value inside eq().

Answer (score 0):

```
$("option[value='B']").after("<option value=\"C\">Charlie</option>");
```

More information in after() and insertAfter() (both doing the same bt taking different ways) in the [official docu](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/):

```
$("#list option[value=D]").before("<option value='C'>Charlie</option>");
```

This will insert the new option `Charlie`, specified by the parameter, before the option `Delta`.

Comment: This will fail as soon as an Option E exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with attribute selectors:

```
$("<option value=\"C\">Charlie</option>").insertAfter($('#list option[value*="B"]'));
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PKBpQ/)