# sort a select list alphabetically using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list with options :
    
    
    Select City,
    Seattle,
    Newyork,
    Amsterdam
     Other
    
    
i want  to keep the select city as it is and just sort the city names also the other option on last.
Select City
Amsterdam
Newyork
Seattle
Other

Comment: Add the code to the question

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Answer (score -1):

please see
[Sorting options elements alphabetically using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073270/sorting-options-elements-alphabetically-using-jquery)

you can easly set aftewards `$("#myselect").val("currentCity")`;