# How can I make a filter like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found a demo with a `filter` and `sort` function that has almost all I need.
The problem isn’t that I want to sort them under each other.

You guys can see it here what I mean: http://1337zone.WIN

These boxes under the filter buttons need to be under each other, not next to each other. They did it in JavaScript I think. When I delete JS files it doesn’t work at all.

The best option is to do it myself. I was searching it for a long time and I just gave up — I don’t understand JavaScript.

It basically look like this:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="element-item metal transition green" data-category="transition">
    <h5 class="name">Hallo</h5>
    <p class="symbol">7</p>
    <p class="number">153</p>
    <p class="weight">53</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid blue" data-category="metalloid">
    <h5 class="name">Hello</h5>
    <p class="symbol">1</p>
    <p class="number">521</p>
    <p class="weight">12</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metal post-transition cyan" data-category="post-transition">
    <h5 class="name">Hi</h5>
    <p class="symbol">3</p>
    <p class="number">83</p>
    <p class="weight">20</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metal post-transition cyan" data-category="post-transition">
    <h5 class="name">Was?</h5>
    <p class="symbol">3</p>
    <p class="number">82</p>
    <p class="weight">20</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the class you can see `"cyan"`, `"blue"`, `"green"` and this code:

```
<button class="button" data-filter=".green">green</button>
```

does some magic and makes it work. Don’t ask me how because I have no idea how.

Is it possible to do it in HTML and CSS only?

Comment: It's not possible...it needs javascript...which is not the same a java. *That's* why it didn't work when you deleted the JS file.

Comment: Thank you for the anwser ! :D Can you give me any tips or link some tutorials where it's explained how to do it because i just cant find any.

Comment: Just google filter with jquery?

Comment: looks like isotope plugin http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: i recommend to you start here http://www.w3schools.com/ or read any book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without using a plugin in the following way. The value of data filter is get using **[data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** function in jQuery and use that to show items with that class name.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    var classSelector = $(this).data('filter');
    $('.grid .element-item').hide();
    $('.grid').find(classSelector).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.green{
  background-color:green;
}
.cyan{
  background-color:cyan;
}
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="element-item metal transition green" data-category="transition">
    <h5 class="name">Hallo</h5>
    <p class="symbol">7</p>
    <p class="number">153</p>
    <p class="weight">53</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid blue" data-category="metalloid">
    <h5 class="name">Hello</h5>
    <p class="symbol">1</p>
    <p class="number">521</p>
    <p class="weight">12</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metal post-transition cyan" data-category="post-transition">
    <h5 class="name">Hi</h5>
    <p class="symbol">3</p>
    <p class="number">83</p>
    <p class="weight">20</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metal post-transition cyan" data-category="post-transition">
    <h5 class="name">Was?</h5>
    <p class="symbol">3</p>
    <p class="number">82</p>
    <p class="weight">20</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="button" data-filter=".green">green</button>
<button class="button" data-filter=".cyan">cyan</button>
<button class="button" data-filter=".blue">blue</button>
```

Comment: right ... but question was "Is it possible to do it ONLY in HTML and CSS ?" answer is NO

Comment: @daremachine check the OP's comments.

Comment: i checked but comments are not question =) but your solution is clean and good

Comment: I understand this script a little it's easier than i thought, the script from the demo is so long that i was shocked and i couln't breath.

Coud you please explain me the part from

Var to show ?

Comment: @1337zoneWIN  `$(this).data('filter')` gets the value of the clicked button's `data-filter` attribute value. Which is like `.green` and that is the jquery selector for class `green`.

Comment: @1337zoneWIN then we hide all `$('.grid .element-item').hide();` divs. Then show only the divs with class you selected using `$('.grid').find(classSelector).show();` the resultant of this line will be like `$('.grid').find('.green').show();`

Comment: Okay i understand, wow you explained it so easy that even i understood it O.o

So if i want to show ALL do i need to make it like:

<button class="button" data-filter=".element-item">green</button>

for the easiest way ?

I have also an other problem, i uploadet in on my FTP and it don't work somehow :(

Comment: @1337zoneWIN if you put `data-filter=".element-item"`, then it will show all the elements on click of the button.

Comment: Hi i think i broke something. http://1337zone.win/

Comment: I add the script, made files and hmm it was working some time and then it somehow stop :(

Comment: @1337zoneWIN that is because you haven't included jQuery library.

Comment: @1337zoneWIN https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-mobile/getting-started/

Comment: I guess this did it:
<script src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js "></script>

Comment: @1337zoneWIN add that before you added `<script src="javascript.js"></script>`, and see the change I made in the answer. use that `$(document).ready(function() {`.

Comment: When i add this $(document).ready(function() { it doesn't wor even on fiddle. Without $(document).ready(function() { it works on fiddle.

It was working for some time and then it just STOP working dont know why.

Comment: I have it like this.
https://jsfiddle.net/1337zoneWIN/54pbeLq1/3/

And it works here but not on FTP lolz

Comment: It works now i need to change it from:
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
to
<script src="http://1337zone.win/jquery.js"></script>

Sorry for being annoying just sorry, how can i sort things ?

With this:

    <p class="symbol">7</p>
    <p class="number">153</p>
    <p class="weight">53</p>

Comment: @1337zoneWIN add new questions for out of this question's scope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073270/sorting-options-elements-alphabetically-using-jquery this might help you.

Comment: It's again me, how can i edit the javascript that i can use 2 buttons ? i mean that i can select two filters at the same time "green" and "blue" and it shows me green and blue without cyan