# Insert in 2 different select only the checked item of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have various checkboxes with the same name:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="A">A
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="B">B
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="C">C
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="D">D
<select name="S1">
   <option value=""></option>
</select>
 <select name="S2">
   <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Every change status, I wish that in the two select there are only checked values.
Example:
If I check A and C, the 2 SELECT will be:

```
<select name="S1">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<select name="S2">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

If I uncheck A and check D (So C remain):

```
    <select name="S1">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="C">C</option>
       <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
    <select name="S2">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="C">C</option>
       <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
```

and so on...

Comment: use jquery html to rewrite the content of S1 or S2 to match the checked boxes.

Comment: How? :D I'm a newbie of jquery e javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below working snnipet.

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change",function(){
  if($(this). prop("checked") == true){
    $("select[name='S1'],select[name='S2']").append('<option value="'+$(this).val()+'">'+$(this).val()+'</option>');
  }else{
    $("select[name='S1'] option[value='"+$(this).val()+"'],select[name='S2'] option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="A">A
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="B">B
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="C">C
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="D">D
<select name="S1">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<select name="S2">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example: https://jsfiddle.net/mccoe8v6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".convocati").click(function(){
     var thisVal = $(this).val();
     debugger;
     if ($(this).is(":checked"))
     {
        $(".convatiSelect").append($("<option>").attr('value', thisVal).html(thisVal));
      }
     else{
       var option = $(".convatiSelect").find("option[value='" + thisVal + "']").remove();
     }
  });
});
```

You may want to sort the options after adding them.

Comment: Yes, how can I sort the options?

Comment: There is a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073270/sorting-options-elements-alphabetically-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```js
$('input[type=checkbox][name^=convocati]').change(function() {
  $('select').html('');
  var option = new Option("", "");
  $('select').append($(option));
  $('input[type=checkbox][name^=convocati]:checked').each(function() {
    var option = new Option($(this).val(), $(this).val());
    $('select').append($(option));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="A">A
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="B">B
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="C">C
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="D">D
<select name="S1">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<select name="S2">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following script to make it work as expected

**Please find comments in code below added on each step to get your output**

```
$(function(){

     //First bind a Change event for all checkbox  
     $("inputt[type='checkbox']").change(function(){

     //We will create on array of values which will hold fresh values of all checkboxes on each change
      var values =[];


       // Now we will fill our values array and add values for checked checkboxes
       $("inputt[type='checkbox']").filter(":checked").each(function(){
             values.push($(this).val());
        }
  );

  // Once we get all values which are checked, we just need to create option template like following
   var options= "";
   for(i=0; i< values.length;i++)
   {
       options+="<option>" + values[i] + "</option>";     
    }

    // SET INNER HMTL of target select once with option template
    $("select[name=S1]").html(options);
    $("select[name=S2]").html(options);
  });
});


<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="A">A
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="B">B
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="C">C
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="D">D
<select name="S1">
   <option value=""></option>
</select>
 <select name="S2">
   <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Please check the **[working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejh0Lr1v/14/)**

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use `map()` to build an array from the checked checkboxes which contains the required HTML and then set it as the `html()` of the `select()` elements. Try this:

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  var html = '<option value=""></option>';
  html += $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return '<option value="' + this.value + '">' + this.value + '</option>';
  }).get().join('');

  $('select').html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="A">A
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="B">B
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="C">C
<input type="checkbox" name="convocati[]" value="D">D

<select name="S1">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<select name="S2">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Note that this is using generic selectors, such as `:checkbox` and `select`. In a production environment I'd strongly suggest you give your elements some classes which you can use to identify them more specifically.

Comment: Yes, of course! This is only a simply example. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.