# How to change order in dropdown to replace item

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Is it possible to change the order in the dropdown to replace an item?

[image]

I need to change it to alphabetic order. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting options elements alphabetically using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073270/sorting-options-elements-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Please find below snippet to sort selectlist

```js
$("#mSelect").append($("#mSelect option").remove().sort(function(a, b) {
    var at = $(a).text(), bt = $(b).text();
    return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mSelect" >
    <option value="val1" > DEF </option>
    <option value="val4" > GRT </option>
    <option value="val2" > ABC </option>
    <option value="val3" > OPL </option>
    <option value="val5" > AWS </option>
    <option value="val9" > BTY </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Small Correction: Added last line for clearing default option selection

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mSelect" >
    <option value="val1" > DEF </option>
    <option value="val4" > GRT </option>
    <option value="val2" > ABC </option>
    <option value="val3" > OPL </option>
    <option value="val5" > AWS </option>
    <option value="val9" > BTY </option>
</select>

$("#mSelect").append($("#mSelect option").remove().sort(function(a, b) {
    var at = $(a).text(), bt = $(b).text();
    return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);
}));

$("#mSelect").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no such option. A jQuery-Hacky method may be possible, but I wouldn't try it. Basically if you want this, you should create an issue on github, but you'll probably have to contribute the code :)