# jQuery how to append under in option menu to specify item

Tags: php, jquery

I have this database driven php option menu, if the page is refreshed then all option items show correctly indented.

If I add a new option item and the page is not refreshed then the new option item does not appear in option menu.

Then I write that jQuery code so that if I add a new item to the option menu, it is appended via jQuery but it is not append to correct place.

Example: If I select COMPUTERS and if I write a text value inside the textbox as "Desktop Computers" it is appended under the option menu, but I want it to append under the COMPUTERS option value.

How can I do that, thanks.

```js
            $("#katID").change(function() {
                var secilitext = $("#katID option:selected").text();
                var sonuc = secilitext.split(" - ");
                //console.log(sonuc);
                var cizgisayisi2 = (sonuc.length);
                var cizgisayisi = (cizgisayisi2 - 1); //sayılar sı
                var katID = $("#katID option:selected").val();
                console.log("ÇİZGİ SAYISI = " + cizgisayisi2);
                console.log("KAT ID = " + katID);

                if (katID != 0 && cizgisayisi == 0){

                    cizgisayisi = 1;
                    console.log("cizgisayisi 1 : " + cizgisayisi);
                    var gizli = $("input[name='cizgisayisi']").val(cizgisayisi);

                }else if(katID == 0){

                    cizgisayisi = 0;
                    console.log("cizgisayisi 2 : " + cizgisayisi);
                    var gizli = $("input[name='cizgisayisi']").val(cizgisayisi);

                }else{

                    cizgisayisi2;
                    console.log("cizgisayisi 3 : " + cizgisayisi2);
                    var gizli = $("input[name='cizgisayisi']").val(cizgisayisi2);
                }



                //.append(new Array(++cizgisayisi).join



            });


       $("form#SayfaYukleForm").on("submit", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var eklenecekveri = new FormData(this);
                var baslik = $('#baslik').val();


                $.ajax({
                    url: "add to option menu.php",
                    method: "post",
                    data: eklenecekveri,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(sonuc) {

                        if (sonuc.ok) {

                            anamenukayitListe();
                            var son_id = sonuc.son_eklenen_id; // last_id has the last insert id
                            var cizgisayisi = sonuc.cizgisayisi;

                                $('#katID').append($('<option>', {
                                    value: (son_id),
                                    text: " - ".repeat(cizgisayisi) + baslik
                                }));




                            $("form#SayfaYukleForm").trigger("reset");
                            //form yollanınca formdaki kalan verileri resetlemek temizlemek için
                            $("#anamenuKayitEkle").html(sonuc.ok).fadeIn(700);
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $("#anamenuKayitEkle").html(sonuc.ok).fadeOut(700);
                                //location.reload();
                            }, 2000);

                            $("#summernote").summernote("reset"); //summernote textarea alanınındaki yazıları boşalt.
                        } else if (sonuc.hata) {
                            $("#anamenuKayitEkle").html(sonuc.hata).fadeIn(700);
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $("#anamenuKayitEkle").html(sonuc.hata).fadeOut(700);

                            }, 2000);
                        }

                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                    }


                });
            });
            //kayıt ekle
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="baslik" name="baslik">
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="katID" name="katID">
<option value="">Select A Category</option>
<option value="0">TOP MENU</option>
<option value="166">ELECTRONICS</option>
<option value="167"> - COMPUTERS</option>
<option value="170"> -  - DESKTOPS</option>
<option value="172"> -  -  - ASUS DESKTOP</option>
<option value="169"> -  - NOTEBOOKS</option>
<option value="168"> -  - TABLETS</option>
<option value="171"> -  -  - SAMSUNG TABLETS</option>
<option value="173"> - TELEVISIONS</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can append at last and then can sort all options. you can check this link for sorting option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073270/sorting-options-elements-alphabetically-using-jquery

Comment: Your brackets and parenthesis in your jQuery isn't matching up.

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: if i use sort method by ids, there was different values integers is it sort to correct places as indented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I select COMPUTERS and if I write a text value inside the textbox as "Desktop Computers" it is appended under the option menu, but I want it to append under the COMPUTERS option value.

You currently append the new option at the bottom with:
').append($('', {
        value: (son_id),
        text: " - ".repeat(cizgisayisi) + baslik
    })

Instead, use `.after()` to append the new option after the selected one:

```
$('#katID>option:checked').after($('<option>', {
    value: (son_id),
    text: " - ".repeat(cizgisayisi) + baslik
})
```

Example snippet:

```js
$("select>option:checked").after("<option value='99'>inserted</option>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3" selected>3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

---

If you're worried about the selected item changing during the ajax call, then you can keep a note of the selected ID and restore it, eg:

```
var id = $("#katID").val();
$.ajax({ 
    ...
}).done(function() {
    $("#katID").val(id);
    $("#katID>option:selected").after(...
});
```

or pass the "parent" ID with the ajax request and receive in the ajax response.

Comment: Thanks , it was easy but i can not see that easy method

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="baslik" name="baslik" value="desktop computers ">
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="katID" name="katID">
<option value="">Select A Category</option>
<option value="0">TOP MENU</option>
<option value="166">ELECTRONICS</option>
<option value="167"> - COMPUTERS</option>
<option value="170"> -  - DESKTOPS</option>
<option value="172"> -  -  - ASUS DESKTOP</option>
<option value="169"> -  - NOTEBOOKS</option>
<option value="168"> -  - TABLETS</option>
<option value="171"> -  -  - SAMSUNG TABLETS</option>
<option value="173"> - TELEVISIONS</option>
</select>
<script>
    var options = [];
    var baslik = $('#baslik').val();
    $("#katID option").each(function()
    {
        options.push([$(this).val(),$(this).text()]); 
        var pieces = $(this).text().split(" ");
        var found = false;
        $.each( pieces, function( i, val ) {
            var pieces2 = baslik.split(" ");            
            $.each( pieces2, function( i, val2 ) {
                if(val && val2 && val.toLowerCase().indexOf(val2.toLowerCase()) != -1 && !found){                    
                    options.push(["some_id"," - "+baslik]); 
                    found = true;
                    return false; 
                }
            })  
            if(found)
                return false; 
        })        

    });
    $('#katID') .find('option') .remove();
    $.each( options, function( i, val ) {
        $('#katID').append($('<option>', {
            value: val[0],
            text: val[1]
          }))
    });

</script>
```

Try running this code and modify your code as per you want, this code is running well for the matched elements.

Comment: I made a change.

Comment: Thanks for the update but not append to option menu anything. Am ii mistake somewhere?

Comment: what variable holds the value of textbox, where is the textbox ? put the textbox in question

Comment: i added  textbox in my question, normaly that my codes append to iem on option menu except sorting

Comment: try running this code in some other php file, and test

Comment: thank you very much for your efforts but i fixed it with freedomn-m  method, it was very easy but we can not see

Comment: Yw glad you found the answer