# Dropdown and checkboxes field alphabetic order

Tags: javascript, forms, sorting, dropdown, alphabetic

I have a form and I would like to sort my dropdown and checkboxes field in alphabetic order.
I tried to use a javascript but it is not working.

```
    $(function() {
    var select = $('select');
    select.html(select.find('option').sort(function(x, y) {
    return $(x).text() > $(y).text() ? 1 : -1;
    }));

    // $('select').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
    });
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting options elements alphabetically using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073270/sorting-options-elements-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

It seems we have answer here: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073270/sorting-options-elements-alphabetically-using-jquery).

I'll copy a part of it:

```js
var options = $('select option');
var arr = options.map(function(_, o) { return { t: $(o).text(), v: o.value }; }).get();
arr.sort(function(o1, o2) { return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0; });
options.each(function(i, o) {
  o.value = arr[i].v;
  $(o).text(arr[i].t);
});
```

Comment: You should be flagging this question as a duplicate, not simply cutting and pasting code from the duplicate into an answer.

Comment: @Nick maybe I should. Where is such a button? My review mode is blocked for some days now...

Comment: It's in the row of links under the question tags: `share edit follow close flag`

Comment: @Nick ahh. Thank you.