# jQuery sortable with Select Options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am new to jQuery so this is probably very simple but I can't seem to find an example with using sortable with Select Options. Can it be done?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#list").sortable({})
});

        <select id='list' size='8'>
            <option value="0">Option 0</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
```

I'm able to get sortable to work with other elements, but it does not with the `Select`

Comment: why do you need to do this? cant you refactor the select element to a list item so it conforms to the sortable params

Comment: I already have the list and it needs to be an option list as part of a form. I am trying to avoid having to add another visual element when the list is already there. I guess what I am checking is that jquery sortable isn't designed for options, which appears to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The solution

```
$.fn.sortOptions = function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
        var op = $(this).children("option");
        op.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.text > b.text ? 1 : -1;
        })
        return $(this).empty().append(op);
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
$("select").sortOptions();
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-sort-an-html-selects-options-by-value-while)

Comment: Forgive me. I don't see how this gets or works with the sortable drag and drop interface.

Comment: It's only for sortable select options