# Sort Options in HTML Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is situation like this:

```
<select id="trollSelect">
    <option value="PL">Polish Troll</option>
    <option value="EN">English Troll</option>
    <option value="JP">Japanese Troll</option>
    [...] //more options created dynamically
</select>
```

`Option values` and `Option texts` are unsorted in `Select`. Is this possible to sort this options in JQuery or Javascript by `value` or `text` alphabetically ??

The result should be like that:

```
<select id="trollSelect">
    <option value="EN">English Troll</option>
    <option value="JP">Japanese Troll</option>
    <option value="PL">Polish Troll</option>
    [...] //more options created dynamically
</select>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-sort-an-html-selects-options-by-value-while

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073270/sorting-options-elements-alphabetically-using-jquery

Comment: OK, it seems to be good, but didactically I keep this link http://jsfiddle.net/uVrML/2/ too :)

Answer (score 5):

This code should do it. I've sorted them on their values but this can also be used to sort based on the text.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var opt = $("#trollSelect option").sort(function (a,b) { return a.value.toUpperCase().localeCompare(b.value.toUpperCase()) });
    $("#trollSelect").append(opt);
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_Singh_Rathore/w4C9V/) for the same