# how to sort select options based on values using pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

On a JSP page I have a following declaration:

```
<html:select property="filterBookingTargetId" styleClass="input_middle" >
    <html:option value="0">-all-</html:option>
    <html:options collection="bookTargetTypes" property="key" labelProperty="value"/> 
</html:select>
```

where collection *`bookTargetTypes`* is a set of key-value (int, String) pairs implemented in Java as a HashMap and read by a server.

If I could use jQuery, I would implement it similarly to answers present on the Stack discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-sort-an-html-selects-options-by-value-while). Unfortunately, I can't; nor can I sort those values before they are uploaded to the server i. e. in Java, on the code level.

The underlying question is, how in pure JavaScript can I refer to *`bookTargetTypes`* collection to sort them alphabetically before they are shown on the page?

Example values of "`bookTargetTypes`" collection, after they are rendered on the page, are shown below:

```
<html:option value="5">bbb</html:option>
<html:option value="13">ccC</html:option>
<html:option value="1">Aaa</html:option>
```

[UPDATE]

```
    <script language="javascript">

function sortOptions() {
var options = document.getElementById('myselect').options;
var optionsArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    optionsArray.push(options[i]);
}
optionsArray = optionsArray.sort(function (a, b) {           
    return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - b.innerHTML.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0);    
});

for (var i = 0; i <= options.length; i++) {            
    options[i] = optionsArray[i];
}
options[0].selected = true;
}

sortOptions();
</script>
```

```
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="listSettlementFiles">
<input type="hidden" name="pageNo" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="countPerPage" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="sc" value="">

<div class="search_bar" id="search" name="search_div">
    <table align="center" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <LABEL>Name of channels</LABEL>
                <select name="filterBookingTargetId" id="myselect" class="input_middle">
                <option value="17">Baa</option>
                <option value="15">Paa</option>
                <option value="2">Saaa</option>
                <option value="9">Daaa</option>
                <option value="6">Naaa</option>
                <option value="1">Eaaa</option>
                <option value="14">Sdda</option>
                <option value="7">Raaa</option>
                <option value="22">Pdddaa</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since you said you can't use jquery or can't modify java code. Here is a pure javascript solution. It would be better if you give an id for your select. You can save the options in an array and then use **sort** function by comparing first letter charcode of innerHTML inside each option.

in your HTML give an id

```
<html:select id="myselect" property="filterBookingTargetId" styleClass="input_middle" >
    <html:option value="0">-all-</html:option>
    <html:options collection="bookTargetTypes" property="key" labelProperty="value"/> 
</html:select>
```

**javascript**

```
function sortOptions() {
    var options = document.getElementById('myselect').options;
    var optionsArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        optionsArray.push(options[i]);
    }
    optionsArray = optionsArray.sort(function (a, b) {           
        return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - b.innerHTML.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0);    
    });

    for (var i = 0; i <= options.length; i++) {            
        options[i] = optionsArray[i];
    }
    options[0].selected = true;
}

sortOptions();
```

click here for **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bsm84vft/2/)**

Comment: @cbx44 : Can you post the generated HTML source, by doing view source on your page?

Comment: Sure, I will add it in the answer below because it is too long. I have spotted one issue: instead of id='myselect' putting styleId='myselect' generates a proper tag in html but still the problem occurs.

Comment: I changed my post to [update] . Sorting does not occur because `sortOptions()` function is not called on the site. I wonder why Javascript is not loaded, because when I call `sortOptions()` from Firebug console, everything is perfectly O.K --> values are sorted.
On the JSfiddle site an `onLoad()` is used; here not. Is this a problem?

Comment: @cbx44 : yes.. call this function on window.onload, like `window.onload=sortOptions();`

Comment: Thanks @Amit.rk3 for help, on Firefox everything is fine now. It's only a pity that IE7 does not recognize `window.onload`. When I try different attributes with `select` tag like `onclick` or `onmousedown` still the script is not loaded. Do you have any hints what might work?

Comment: @cbx44 , IE7? are you still using that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not refer to **bookTargetTypes** after the page is rendered.

And if you can not use jQuery, you can only replicate the jQuery behavior using pure javascript.

You can write a onload script which will get triggerred after the page is loaded. In that script you can reorder the options of the particular select element.