# jQuery: Converting a select options list to checkbox list without using multiple?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Current code:

```
<div class="span4">
   <select class="someClass" ng-change="updateSearchResults()">
            <option value="1">Upcoming Events</option>
            <option value="2">Past Events</option>
            <option value="3">All Events</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Inserting 'multiple' seems to break the list so I'd like to avoid using 'multiple'. Is it possible to convert this select options list into a checkbox list?

jQuery or Angular is fine. Thanks!

Comment: See the link below for converting select to checkbox list using jQuery

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303607/how-to-convert-select-dropdown-to-multiple-checkbox

Comment: I tried using that method though it also seemed to have caused my code to break so I'd like to insert an id at most.

Comment: Should be able to find an angularjs module that does checkbox list then include it as a dependency in your app module or any other module that is already a dependency