# Sorting through multiple select options efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery, programming in general, but have been experimenting with it for the last couple of days in relation so sorting multiple select option dropdowns alphabetically. I have come up with a solution but I am sure there is a far more efficient way to write this but at this time it is beyond me. How to I go through each select without calling them directly? It needs to happen on page load without user interaction.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    $("select[name='properties[Flavour 1]']").html($("select[name='properties[Flavour 1]'] option").sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
    }))
    $("select[name='properties[Flavour 1]']").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
  //Flavour 2
    $("select[name='properties[Flavour 2]']").html($("select[name='properties[Flavour 2]'] option").sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
    }))
    $("select[name='properties[Flavour 2]']").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
  //Flavour 3
    $("select[name='properties[Flavour 3]']").html($("select[name='properties[Flavour 3]'] option").sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
    }))
    $("select[name='properties[Flavour 3]']").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
}, false);
```

This continues on until Flavour 12 but you get the idea of how it is set out.

Comment: Add a class to the `select`s you want to act on, then use `each` to go over each of them. You probably want to set a variable for each `select` and use `find` to get the options, rather than using a selector.

Comment: What is providing the 12 flavors? Usually you would want to sort the data before it makes it to the display...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting options elements alphabetically using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073270/sorting-options-elements-alphabetically-using-jquery)

Comment: @Jarvis It's a separate app I use on the store which doesn't provide the option to sort it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I cannot add a class/do not know how to add a class to them unfortunately.

Comment: In the HTML, after `<select` add `class="flavour"`. Then use `$('select.flavour').each(...`

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't believe I have access to those files, it is supplied by the app and if I can access it then I am unsure where.

Comment: Each of the selectors is within its own div class, can I sort through those instead?

Comment: You should do some research into [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and how they work. I don't really have the time (nor is SO built for) the back and forth for teaching.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the resource, I wasn't asking with the intention of having one to one help, I just wanted to check if I was missing something painfully obvious in my existing solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a generic solution, I added a wrapper so I could get the count and not hard code the number or pollute the global DOM.  I added a document level alternative but remove it if you can.

NOTE: After thinking this over a bit I noted your "Flavours" spelling and concluded that this may need some localization SO, I modified the sort to use that instead.
   `return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);`

I also added classes to show those were retained as well as any selected default adjustment to retain the prior value.

For the second example I compacted all that down to a shorter jQuery version, expand that to see it there.

More here on the sorting specifics: [What is the most efficient way to sort an Html Select's Options by value, while preserving the currently selected item?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45888/125981)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let myflavours = $('#flavours').find('select[name^="properties[Flavour"]').length;
  //alternate
  let myflavoursNotAsGood = $(document).find('select[name^="properties[Flavour"]').length;
  console.log(myflavoursNotAsGood);
  for (let f = 1; f <= myflavours; f++) {
    let sel = $("select[name='properties[Flavour " + f + "]']");
    let v = sel.val();
    let opts = sel.find("option").sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);
    });
    sel.html(opts).val(v);
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.water {
  color: blue;
}

.drink {
  color: orange;
}

.yuk {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flavours">
  <select name='properties[Flavour 1]'>
    <option>Cheese</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option selected="selected">Cotton Candy</option>
    <option>Blueberry</option>
    <option class="yuk">Rotten Eggs</option>
    <option class="water">Swamp Water</option>
    <option class="water">Swamp Scum</option>
  </select>
  <select name='properties[Flavour 2]'>
    <option>Cheese</option>
    <option>Apple Smoked Bacon</option>
    <option selected="selected">Blueberry</option>
    <option class="yuk">Rotten Eggs</option>
    <option class="drink">Bier</option>
    <option>Bacon</option>
    <option class="water">Swamp Water</option>
    <option class="water">Swamp Scum</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Second example built differently than yours a bit.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#flavours').find('select[name^="properties[Flavour"]')
    .each(function(index, element) {
      let v = element.value;
      $(this).html($(this).find("option").sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);
      })).val(v);
    });
});
```

```css
.water {
  color: blue;
}

.drink {
  color: orange;
}

.yuk {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flavours">
  <select name='properties[Flavour 1]'>
    <option>Cheese</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option selected="selected">Cotton Candy</option>
    <option>Blueberry</option>
    <option class="yuk">Rotten Eggs</option>
    <option class="water">Swamp Water</option>
    <option class="water">Swamp Scum</option>
  </select>
  <select name='properties[Flavour 2]'>
    <option>Cheese</option>
    <option>Apple Smoked Bacon</option>
    <option selected="selected">Blueberry</option>
    <option class="yuk">Rotten Eggs</option>
    <option class="drink">Bier</option>
    <option>Bacon</option>
    <option class="water">Swamp Water</option>
    <option class="water">Swamp Scum</option>
  </select>
</div>
```